# Can Cannabis plant ashes be used for soil amendment?

Tags: plant-health, soil-amendment, toxicity, potash

In [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/43785/44275), somebody asked whether *Nicotiana* (tobacco) ashes can be used to amend soil. The answer is more involved than simply considering the ashes as [potash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potash), because the ashes of specific species can contain harmful elements, molecules, viruses, etc.

**Can *Cannabis* ashes be used to amend soil?** I have a friend who follows the same pattern as in that other question, but they are smoking *Cannabis* instead. They save their ashes in a small tray and add that tray to their potting soil. Is this effective, harmful, both, or neither?

Comment: Ants run from a smoky smell. Empty any ashtrays around plants where you see ants. Not for the soil, for the ants. Tobacco okay, too.